# Almacenar resultado select

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

En un post anterior pregunte esto: [Descargar objeto seleccionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72628/descargar-objeto-seleccionado) y gracias a un usuario me dio la idea, la cual la agradezco muchisimo. Pero ahora tengo otra duda, y como tengo que tener 50 de respeto para poder responder y demas, pues hago otro post.

Y la pregunta ahora es:
¿Hay alguna manera de almacenar el resultado de un select? Es decir, almacenar que se ha seleccionado en el "select" y luego guardarlo en una variable y usarlo.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, el otro post ciérralo, ya que no tiene una solución completa y añade en este el código que tienes actualmente contando con las modificaciones que cogiste del otro post

Comment: La otra pregunta está más clara que esta, de hecho se pueden considerar como duplicadas. Puedes introducir el select en un formulario e incluso _escuchar_ el evento `on change` del mismo a través de Ajax/jQuery, lanzando en background una acción cualquiera cada vez que se selecciona un valor en el select. Dicha acción en backgroun lanzaría una operación (la que desees) en el servidor y te traería los datos que desees para presentarlos en pantalla o hacer otra cosa... todo ello sin moverse de la página desde la cual se hizo la opción en el select. Encontrarás aquí muchos ejemplos de eso.

Comment: @G3l0 Soy nuevo en la pagina y no se como cerrar, asi que vere como. Y A. Cedano no entiendo eso que me dices...

Comment: Pues si, es mejor jugar con AJAX y JQuery, pero como su pregunta era sobre PHP preferí ceñirme a lo preguntado.. @A.Cedano

Comment: El se refiere a que usando AJAX y JQuery, que no se si controlarás, lances una petición al hacer click en el botón de descargar y que esta petición se encargue de acceder a la BD y hacerte la consulta con el valor del select seleccionado.  También te propone que cada vez que cambies el elemento seleccionado hagas la petición, pero para el fin que quieres lograr no creo que sea lo óptimo.

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que puedes tener tu select en un archivo PHP/HTML y usar jQuery/Ajax para detectar cada vez que se selecciona un valor en el mismo. Luego, a través de Ajax recuperas el valor de la opción seleccionada y lanzas una acción cualquiera (por ejemplo consultar a la base de datos filtrando por ese id seleccionado) y recuperando los datos que el servidor envíe al hacerle la consulta. No sería necesario siquiera tener un botón submit, puedes lanzar la acción cada vez que se cambie de opción en el select y la página no tendría que refrescarse cada vez que lances una acción.

Comment: Es buena idea el evento change, pero generar un csv cada vez que se lance.. ¿no es adecuado no? puede que me equivoque @A.Cedano

Comment: Yo por desgracia solo controlo php (mas o menos), mysql (Aprendiendo) y html, y estoy aprendiendo python, soy mas o menos nuevo en estos mundos... Mirare eso de `on change` porque sera de lo que controlo... Gracias a ambos.

Comment: @G3l0 Eso depende. Si **la última acción** es elegir algo en el select no veo problema en generar el CSV usando el evento `on change`, otra cosa sería si, luego de hacer el select habría que rellenar más campos... entonces sí habría que hacerlo desde el `submit`, pero en mi caso, si la última opción es seleccionar, generaría el CSV al seleccionar, se estaría ahorrando así un paso innecesario: hacer select -> presionar en el botón descargar. Eso depende del contexto, el cual no conozco totalmente.

Comment: onchange es el evento que se lanza cuando cambias el elemento de un select, para ello deberás usar javascript

Comment: me pasa lo mismo xD, pero yo creo que si no sabe de javascript y demás, sería mejor que lo intentase en PHP que controla algo más @A.Cedano  PD: tienes toda la razón con esto último, no lo pensé así

Comment: A. Cenado Esto es como esta [http://imgur.com/a/0QSJd ] quiero que simplemente selecciones, le des al boton, y se genere el archivo csv con los datos con otra columna que no se muestra, y tiene datos...

Comment: Aunque no domines Javascript, no tengas miedo de lanzarte a aprender lo básico, ya que en estos casos te ahorrará muchos dolores de cabeza y facilitará las cosas. Aprender lo básico no es tan difícil. jQuery es podríamos decir una librería de Javascript. Comprenderás las diferencias y similitudes en la medida en que vayas investigando. Te será muy útil aprender a usar PHP/HTML combinado con Javascript (puro o mediante una librería como jQuey u otra). Saludos.

Comment: Viendo la imagen, no es necesario, en este caso, el botón descargar. Y para que veas que no es tan complicado, ahora publicaré una respuesta usando HTML combinado con Javascript (usando la biblioteca jQuery).

Comment: @A.Cedano tiene razón, no te vendría mal, haciendo desarrollo web, aprender algo de javascript y jquery, un saludo :D

Comment: @A.Cedano Oky, investigare de eso mientras :D. Tendre que empezar javascript y jquery...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPbFiM-HA4lwJH12JXdXxDA este canal de youtube es de donde yo aprendí, es bastante completo y ayuda bastante, espero te sirva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te muestro un ejemplo simple de HTML combinado con jQuery. En el HTML se agrega la librería jQuery mediante la línea: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Verás que luego jQuery *escucha* el evento `on change` del `select` lanzando una acción cada vez que cambias de opción.

En esta parte del código:

`$('select').on('change', function() {...`
puedes lanzar cualquier tipo de acción: peticiones al servidor, consulta de base de datos, consultar APIs externas... y presentar tus datos en la misma página. Verás que cuando seleccionas una opción el contenido del div se cambia de forma dinámica, sin tener que cambiar de página.

Para probar, pulsa el botón azul <kbd>Ejecutar</kbd>.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  textohtml = '<p>Has seleccionado el valor: <b>' + this.value + '</b><br />'+
  'Desde aquí puedes enviar peticiones al servidor. Por ejemplo, consultar la BD usando el id cuyo valor es el seleccionado, en este caso: ' + this.value+
  '</p><p>Cambia a otro valor y verás <b>como el contenido se actualiza de forma dinámica</b> :)</p>' ;
  $('#result').html(textohtml);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="0">-Seleccione Fecha-</option>
    <option value="1">1. 2017-05-01</option>
    <option value="2">2. 2017-05-02</option>
    <option value="3">3. 2017-05-03</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Nota:** Es un ejemplo básico, y como dice @G3l0 en su comentario, puedes escuchar cualquier elemento del documento html sea por tipo de elemento, como en este ejemplo, en el cual se escucharía el `on change`de cualquier `select`, pero puedes escuchar tus elementos en particular, usando el id de los mismos, puedes escuchar también por el nombre de la clase, o por grupos de elementos, como suele ser el caso de los radio buttons para selecciones múltiples, etc, etc.

Las opciones son muchísimas. Y decir también que puedes actualizar desde jQuery cualquier cosa de tu documento HTML actual: valores de inputs, contenido de elementos `<div>, <p>, <span>`, etc, colores de texto o de fondo, aplicando reglas CSS desde el mismo jQuery... en fin, todo un abanico de posiblidades :) ...

Comment: Un apunte de nada, si tu etiqueta select tiene un ID y tiene más select en  la misma página, puedes hacer esto para que solo te registre el evento del select que te interesa: `$('#idDelSelect').on('change', function() {` @Straxy

Comment: Buena respuesta A. Cedano

Comment: Vuelvo a ponerte el canal donde te explican javascript por si no lo has visto @Straxy https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPbFiM-HA4lwJH12JXdXxDA

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias a ambos, ya lo tengo casi listo.